# treat list of numpy arrays as a numpy object

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using a data object that is a list of numpy arrays of different shapes. I would like to treat the data object as a single numpy object, such that I can add, subtract and scale these objects as if they were pure numpy arrays:

```
# Defining the data objects:
d1 = [numpy.random.rand(n**2).reshape(n, n) for n in range(1, 5)]
d2 = [numpy.random.rand(n**2).reshape(n, n) for n in range(1, 5)]

# The operation I want to perform:
d3 = [a1 + 2*a2 for a1, a2 in zip(d1, d2)]

# What I really would like to write:
d3 = d1 + 2*d2   # (not valid for lists of arrays)
```

What is the easiest way to define the objects d1 and d2 such that I can use the last line?

The reason I ask is because I want to reuse some code that assumes that d1 and d2 are simple numpy arrays that can be added and scaled.

Comment: @Moses Koledoye: The shapes of the arrays match. See the example.

Comment: Pay attention to `shape` and  `dtype` when creating an array from these lists.  Since the subarrays differ in shape, the combination will be a 1d array of array objects, not a multidimensional array of floats. Some, but not all, numpy math propagates through those objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply defining them as `numpy.array` works:

```
d1 = numpy.array([numpy.random.rand(n**2).reshape(n, n) for n in range(1, 5)])
d2 = numpy.array([numpy.random.rand(n**2).reshape(n, n) for n in range(1, 5)])
d3 = d1 + 2 * d2
```

Or if you want to keep `d1` and `d2` as regular lists you can use `numpy.asarray`:

```
d1_ = numpy.asarray(d1)
d2_ = numpy.asarray(d2)
d3 = d1_ + 2 * d2_
```

Comment: What does `asarray` do that's different?

Comment: @hpaulj nothing. I just meant it as an option if one already has the lists stored somewhere and does not want to change the defining lines